# How to show (or refute) that point pair connecting geodesic segments are locally uniqe on a Riemann manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, diffeomorphism

I believe it is correct to say that **for every point on a Riemann manifold there is a sufficiently small nice neighborhood within which every point pair determines exactly one connecting geodesic segment.**

Is this a correct statement?  Is it an axiom or a theorem?  If it is a theorem, how is it proved?

Comment: Such a statement is only true if you look at complete Riemannian manifolds, and if you add the requirement that the connecting geodesic segment has to be minimizing. You cannot exclude the existence of another (then not minimizing) geodesic joining the two points. Apart from that follow the advice from @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: @Thomas Can't the neighborhood be made small enough to disallow maximizing geodesics?  I am assuming that all points of allowable connecting geodesics lie in the neighborhood.  So if there are both a maximizing and a minimizing connecting geodesic, the maximizing curve will exceed the boundary and thus not be allowed.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton If you request that the geodesic has to lie within that neighbourhood, then yes. Again, look up the concept of a geodesically convex neighbourhood. From the formulation of your question it is not clear to me whether you include this requirement. Without this requirement, no - just have a look at a shpere in Eucliedean three space, where each great circle is a closed geodesic.

Comment: I was just wondering why Misner Thorne and Wheeler don't require geodesics as the transport paths connecting tangent spaces in Figure 10.2; RE the final paragraph. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntlBf.png The nonuniqueness will only arise when two or more arbitrary geodesic parallel transport displacements are performed sequentially.  So we can uniquely connect all neighboring tangent spaces as long as we refer them all to the tangent space at one specific point.

Comment: My suggestion is to read a different textbook in differential geometry. The one you are reading is sloppy, unclear and non-mathematical. No wonder that you are confused. My favorite would be do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry" (first 4 chapters).

Comment: @MoisheKohan  The book I referenced is a classic textbook on general relativity.  Upon reflection, I now realize (believe) the answer to my question is: Yes.  This is the inverse mapping theorem.  I'm still uncertain which is the chicken and which is the egg.  If, by differentiable manifold we mean a structured set of points diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n,$ then it seems that invertibility (and thereby uniqueness) is given.